# Remove indentation of first

Tags: context

I'm using Context (2017.10.15 12:29) and having trouble with in-margin headings.

In particular, I want to have the first paragraph following an in-margin heading to not be indented.  The picture below shows the sample compiled, with the red arrow highlighting where the indentation ought to be removed.

In spite of numerous settings that one might expect to achieve this, none of the many combinations I have tried have yielded the outcome desired.

Here is a minimum example, showing the various settings I suspected may be involved.

```
\define[2]\MarginLeftHead{\margintitle[]{#2}}
\definelayout[subsectioninmargins][
    backspace=2in,
    width=5in,
]
\setuplayout[subsectioninmargins]
\setuphead[subsection][
    after=,
    align={flushleft,nothyphenated,verytolerant},
    aligntitle=no,
    alternative=text,
    before=,
    beforesection=,
    command=\MarginLeftHead,
    commandafter=,
    commandbefore=,
    distance=0pt,
    inbetween=,
    indentnext=no,
    interlinespace=-15pt,
    number=no,
    strut=no,
    style={\tfx},
    textstyle={\tfx},
]

\starttext
    \subsection{This is an arbitrary title}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\stoptext
```

[image]

How might one setup a header such that no indent occurs for the paragraph immediately following?

Ideally the solution would not affect headings / paragraphs elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the section title into the margin you can use the `margintext` alternative. The alignment for the text in the margin has to be set with the `\margindata` command.

```
\setuplayout
  [backspace=2in,
   width=middle]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [alternative=margintext,
   style=\tfx]

\setupmargindata
  [margintext:section]
  [align={flushleft,nothyphenated,verytolerant}]

\showframe[text][leftmargin,text]

\starttext

\subsection{This is an arbitrary title}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\stoptext
```

[image: Section title in the page margin]

Comment: Thanks Metafox.  Two questions, If may:  First, as this isn't documented at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead, how would one discover this option?  Second, how might one remove the leading vertical space above the margin title (i.e. above "1  This is an")?

Comment: The `margintext` alternative is mentioned in the command reference (http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf). To raise the position of the first line of the margin text you can use the `dy` key for `\setupmargindata` (`\setupmargindata[margintext:section][dy=-2pt]`).

Comment: Incidentally, for those who wander here, I've opened a related question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415332/margin-headers-and-inter-paragraph-space-or-indentnext?noredirect=1&lq=1