# Margin headers and inter-paragraph space or indentnext

Tags: context

Following my recent question [Remove indentation of first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415304/remove-indentation-of-first/415313#415313), I've encountered some curiosities.

The solution @Metafox gave works great when paragraphs are flush left and have no inter-paragraph spacing. However both of those break the proposal (or at least they do not operate as one expects / per the documentation).

However, it doesn't work as expected with either:

1. `\setupwhitespace[big]`
2. `\setupindenting[yes,next,medium]`

In particular, when `setupwhitespace` is given, it displays as follows:

[image: bad whitespace]

The whitespace ought to only be present when between paragraphs.

Similarly with indenting, the `next` and `indentnext` options do not appear to be respected:

[image: what about next]

```
\setuplayout
  [backspace=2in,
   width=middle]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [alternative=margintext,
   style=\tfx]

\setupmargindata
  [margintext:section]
  [align={flushleft,nothyphenated,verytolerant}]

\setupwhitespace[big] %<<<
\setupindenting[yes,next,medium] %<<<

\showframe[text][leftmargin,text]

\starttext

\subsection{This is an arbitrary title}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\stoptext
```

How can one employ the flush-left `margintext` from the related question alongside inter-paragraph spacing and paragraph indenting?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in newer versions of context: If I run your example with the version included in TL2017 (2017.05.15 21:48) the output is as expected, while the latest beta (2018.02.14 22:56) has the "curiosities" you mention. You should write to the context mailing list.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt The bug is fixed in version `2018.02.21 18:19`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Metafox.  I've added an answer so this can be marked as answered, but please feel free to post your comment as an answer for credit.  Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this turned out to be a bug which is fixed in the latest beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Metafox posted, this bug is fixed in 2018.02.21 18:19.